# String not serializable exception coming for interned strings from Wicket Model (on JRockit/Weblogic)

Tags: spring, weblogic, wicket, jrockit

The following seems to be a bug with JRockit or Weblogic, but maybe
someone on this list has seen it before and has a better
workaround/solution.
We have been developing a Wicket application for a government agency
that is going to be used by 15k users. The application will be
deployed on a Weblogic cluster running on JRockit and Red Hat.
We have been experiencing strange "Model object not serializable"
exceptions coming from Model and traced it back to interned (by the
compiler) String objects becoming not serializable after hitting the
server with a few hundred parallel users. Once the exception occurs
for a given String reference it keeps coming consistently for that
reference.
The current workaround is a custom Model class that has an overrided
setObject method which checks the object if it's instanceof
Serializable and if the check fails it sets new String(object) on the
Model. This eliminates the exceptions but would like a better solution
to the problem.
Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: weblogic version: 10.3.3

Comment: Also, the exception does not occur with Sun jvm

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem using jrockit R28.0.1-21-133393-1.6.0_20-20100512-2126-linux-x86_64. After some stress to my application wicket model complains about strings not being serializable. I'm unable to replicate the situation using -Xdebug flag enabled to see what's actually passed to Model.setObject() method. It looks like my only hope is to switch back to sun jvm.